# How to convert two arrays into single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to convert two arrays into a single array base on given below condition.
a= ["dry chapati", "dry chapati", "dry chapati"]
b = ["chapati", "less fat", "no oil"];

I want to convert a and b to as below

c = ["dry chapati" : "chapati", "less fat", "no oil"]

I am trying it as below but not getting desired result as c

```
let recipe = ["dry chapati", "dry chapati", "dry chapati"];
let tags = ["chapati", "less fat", "no oil"];

let r = [];
for(let i=1; i<recipe.length; i++){
    if(recipe[i] == recipe[i+1]){
        recipe[i] = tags
        // console.log(recipe);
    }
}
```

Please help to find a solution.

Comment: Your `c` is not a valid JavaScript object or array...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Needs more details. On what basis we need to make calculations ? What will be the relations between `a` and `b` to assign the tags ?

Comment: This question must have been asked many times before but this one is extremely badly worded and the OP doesn't even have a valid desired result. OP should do more research and will get better answers than asking this again like this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let recipe = ["dry chapati", "dry chapati", "dry chapati"];
let tags = ["chapati", "less fat", "no oil"]; 

let array3 = [...new Set(recipe.concat(tags) )];
console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work, but here its a different scenario that it must print exactly the same as ["dry chapati" : "chapati", "less fat", "no oil"]

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr1 = ["dry chapati", "dry chapati", "dry chapati"];
let arr2 = ["chapati", "less fat", "no oil"];


const merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const res= [arr1[1]];
  arr1.forEach((arr,i) => 
    res.push(`${arr2[i]}`)
    );
    return res;
}

console.log(merge(arr1,arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use merge

> ```
> $a1=array("red","green");
> $a2=array("blue","yellow");
> print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
> ```

Comment: Thats PHP ? OP is asking about JS...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the spread syntax.

```
let recipe = ["dry chapati", "dry chapati", "dry chapati"];
let tags = ["chapati", "less fat", "no oil"];

let result = [...recipe, ...tags];
let result2 = [];
result2.push(...new Set(result));
console.log(result2);
```

This will give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear as what you want to achieve but according to my understanding of the problem. Give below are two possible ways.

```
 /*If you want to achieve something like
  let c = [{'dry chapati': 'chapati'}, {'dry chapati': 'less fat'}, {'dry chapati': 'no oil'} ]
  */
  let thirdArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < recipe.length; i++) {
    let dish = {
      [recipe[i]]: tags[i],
    };
    thirdArray.push(dish);
  }

  /*If you want to achieve something like
  let c = [{'dry chapati': ['chapati', 'less fat', 'no oil']}. {...}]
  */
  let fourthArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    let secondDish = {
      [recipe[i]]: [tags],
    };
    fourthArray.push(secondDish);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use LINQ. Zip in jQuery, you can add (https://github.com/multiplex/multiplex.js) LINQ library JS in your script file and try this code.

var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

var res = arr1.zip(arr2, function(a, b){ return {Num:a, Letter:b} });

Comment: Please try to run a code snippet to show the results rather than a verbal suggestions